# can two strings separated by space be passed to a function? need explanation

Tags: c++, c

I saw a call when reading PX4 code,

```
open(ACCEL_BASE_DEVICE_PATH "0", O_RDONLY)
```

where , `#define ACCEL_BASE_DEVICE_PATH "/dev/accel"`

so, `open("/dev/accel" "0", O_RDONLY)`

is this even possible ?  `"/dev/accel" "0"`

I'm expecting there may be pre processing macro
... But that will hard to find..

Comment: @Jarod42 thanks for cleanup

Comment: Take a look at [this link](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/254984/on-concatenating-adjacent-string-literals) for an interesting history lesson / rationale for why this is supported

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consecutive string literals are concatenated by pre-processor.
It is legal.

`"/dev/accel" "0"` results in `"/dev/accel0"`.

Note that space is irrelevant here (but more readable), it would be the same with `"/dev/accel""0"`.

Note also that, in c++11, because of User-defined literals (UDL), space may be required sometime as for

```
#define ZERO "0"
"/dev/accel"ZERO // Here space is require since C++11. else there is an other meaning.
```

Comment: Guy purporting to teach C in college didn't know this and tried to mark me wrong when I did it in a homework project :p

Comment: (C99, 6.4.5p5) "In translation phase 6, the multibyte character sequences specified by any sequence of adjacent character and identically-prefixed string literal tokens are concatenated into a single multibyte character sequence."